# How Exactly useselector works?

Tags: reactjs, redux, react-redux

As per Doc

```
useSelector(selector: Function, equalityFn?: Function)
```

useSelector accepts two params and second one is optional since by default it compare strict === reference equality check but  not shallow equality.

```
  const state = useSelector(state => {
        console.log("useSelector rerendering");
        return state.counter
    }, shallowEqual)
```

Another is

```
  const state = useSelector(state => {
        console.log("useSelector rerendering");
        return state.counter
    })
```

In both Cases component rerendering when redux store state changes and also when local state changes then it will render (print console.log inside useSelector)

I really didn't understand exactly how it works

Full source code

```
import React, { useState } from 'react'
import { shallowEqual, useDispatch, useSelector } from 'react-redux'
import { decrement, increment } from './store/actions'


export default function CounterHooks(props) {

    const [submit, setSubmit] = useState(false)
    const state = useSelector(state => {
        console.log("useSelector rerendering");
        return state.counter
    }, shallowEqual)


    const dispatch = useDispatch()
 
    console.log("component rerendering");
    const increments = () => {

        dispatch(increment());

    }

    const decrements = () => {

        dispatch(decrement());
    }
    const submitButton = () => {
        console.log("component submit", submit);

        setSubmit((previousState) => !previousState)

    }
    return (
        <div>
            <button onClick={increments} >Incrmeent Counter</button>
            <br />
            <button onClick={decrements} >Decrement Counter</button>
            <br />
            <button onClick={submitButton} >Submit</button>
            <br />

            <h2>total : {state.count}</h2> <br />
            <h2>Submit:{String(submit)}</h2> <br />
           
           
        </div>
    )
}
```

MY question is how exactly second param works ?

Comment: What is your actual question? Is something here behaving differently than you would assume?

Comment: @phry.how exactly second param works.i dont see any difference

Answer (score 17, accepted):

In your example, it does not make a difference.

`shallowEquals` makes sense when you select an object that might be similar in contents, but different by reference.

See these two objects:

```js
const a = { foo: "bar" }
const b = { foo: "bar" }

console.log( a === b ) // will log false
console.log( shallowEquals(a, b)) // will log true
```

While `a` and `b` are two objects with similar shape and contents, they are not the same object.
Now `shallowEquals` does a `===` comparison between `a.foo` and `b.foo` and since both are strings with the same content, `a.foo === b.foo` will be true.

This does play a role if you create a new object in your selector, say

```js
const result = useSelector((state) => {

  return { a: state.foo.bar, b: state.baz.boo }

})
```

The result of this will always be a new object, so per default `useSelector` will always assume they are different, even when `state.foo.bar` and `state.baz.boo` actually did not change.
If you use a `shallowEqual`, `useSelector` will look at the direct (only 1 level deep) child properties of the objects and compare those. Then it will notice that they are in fact equal and not rerender.

Comment: @phry.Thanks for your effort for answering .as per your answer ,if state object value doesn't change then it will not rerender.but  for testing purpose i have returned current state instead of incrementing like  case INCREMENT:
            return {
                ...state, count: state.count
            } but still it rerenders even after adding shallow equal

Comment: @phry.is it possible to give real world example for this use case in react

Comment: The above *is* a real world use case as soon as you replace `foo` with `user`, `bar` with `firstName`, `baz` with `auth` and `boo` with `token`. But there are millions of other use cases.

But realistically: just select single properties from the state in most cases and use multiple useSelector. You will almost never have the need for shallowEqual that way, it's more of an escape hatch.

Answer (score 0):

Consider the below as reducer,

```
const userSlice = (
{name: "user", initialState: {name: "test", isLoggedIn: true}, 
reducers: {updateUser(state, action) => (state.isLoggedIn=action.payload["isLoggedIn"])}
}
```

If we dispatch an action to reducer with same data like below,

```
const result = useSelector(state => state.users)
dispatch({isLoggedIn: true})
```

The above code will not cause the component to re-render, since we the state.users we are referring is same as previous one.

We can make it to re-render with the below changes,

```
    const result = useSelector(state => ({name: state.users.name, isLoggedIn: state.users.isLoggedIn)
dispatch({isLoggedIn: true})
```

In the above code, we are returning an object directly so whenever the useSelector runs the returned objects will not be same due to referential equality. This make component to re-render

Answer (score 0):

With useSelector you can also override the default strategy for rendering.

> This hook takes an optional equality comparison function as the second parameter that allows you to customize the way the selected state is compared to determine whether the component needs to be re-rendered.*

https://github.com/reduxjs/react-redux/blob/master/src/hooks/useSelector.ts