# Redux Toolkit - Configuring selector to remove memoization warnings

Tags: javascript, redux, react-redux, redux-toolkit

In my application, I access state using `useSelector` like so in my `ChatScreen`:

```js
const chatMessages = useSelector(state => {
  if (!chatId) return []
  const messagesData = state.messages.messagesData[chatId] 
  if (!messagesData)  return []
  return messagesData
})
```

`dispatch` is called for each chat and the corresponding message data on mount of the application like so:

```js
dispatch(setChatMessages({ chatId, messagesData }))
```

However, the warning: `WARN  Selector unknown returned a different result when called with the same parameters. This can lead to unnecessary rerenders.` occurs whenever I load onto `ChatScreen`.

Any suggestions to remove this issue? Could I use the `shallowEqual` function is this scenario for the equality function?

EDIT 2:
Selector:

```
  const chatMessages = useSelector(state => state.messages.messagesData[chatId])
```

Logic for flatlist:

```
  <FlatList
    data={chatMessages ? Object.values(chatMessages) : []}
```

My reducer function:

```
setChatMessages: (state, action) => {
    const existingMessages = state.messagesData
    const {chatId, messagesData} = action.payload

    existingMessages[chatId] = messagesData

    state.messagesData = existingMessages
},
```

EDIT 3:

```
  const emptArr = []

  const chatMessages = useSelector(state => {
    if (!chatId) return emptArr
    const messagesData = state.messages.messagesData[chatId] 
    if (!messagesData)  return emptArr
    return messagesData
  })
```

Comment: Well, first I would find useful if you provide a sandbox with more context about how you do what you say. But anyways, in your particular case I think that it would be ok to use shallowEqual because, as stated in [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/67384232/8743364), it will only re-render when the contents of the object change, and not the reference itself. And that is certainly the case for your messagesData object. Hope it helps!

Comment: Does this answer your question? [How Exactly useselector works?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/67384049/how-exactly-useselector-works)

Comment: I think, you're using selectors incorrectly. They are supposed to be simple, hardly ever conditional. Try to always select `state.messages.messagesData[chatId]` (if `chatId` is falsy, this will select `undefined`, which is ok); then do `chatMessages ?? []` but _outside of the selector_. For better reusability consider creating a hook `useChatMessages(chatId)`

Comment: @white-wolf97, unfortunately adding shallowEqual did not solve the problem. The warning persisted

Comment: @ParzhfromUkraine Hello, please check the edit in my post. I did what you suggested, however I still get the same warning. Any suggestions?

Comment: @white-wolf97 Please see the updated post to see the reducer

Answer (score 3):

Your selector creates a new array instance in a couple of circumstances.

`useSelector` relies on the return value from the selector being referentially stable (`prevResult === newResult`) in order to tell when the data has *actually* changed.

```js
const chatMessages = useSelector(state => {
  if (!chatId) return [] // this will create a new array instance every time the selector runs
  const messagesData = state.messages.messagesData[chatId] 
  if (!messagesData)  return [] // this too
  return messagesData
})
```

What you could do is create the empty array instance *outside* your component, and return that stable reference.

```js
const chatMessages = useSelector(state => {
  if (!chatId) return emptyArray; // we made this outside our component, the reference shouldn't change
  const messagesData = state.messages.messagesData[chatId] 
  if (!messagesData)  return emptyArray; // ditto
  return messagesData
})
```

Comment: Hello, please check my latest edit, I implemented your solution however, the same warning persists.

Comment: Also if I remove the `if (!chatid)` and the `if(!messageData)` lines completely, the warning persists.

Comment: are you sure the warning is specifically from that useSelector call?

Comment: Yes it is indeed